# Disable button when move mouse out of control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik

Say I have a Telerik RadGridView, outside there is a button. When the mouse is clicking row in the RadGridView, the button is enabled. If the mouse moves outside the RadGridView, then the button is disabled.

My code is

```
rgv_LostFocus(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
  // do something
   MyViewModel.IsButtonEnabled = false;
}
```

However I don't want to use code behind. Maybe using behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @mm8 hint.

```
<telerik:RadGridView xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Then in ViewModel,

```
public DelegateCommand LostFocusCommand = new DelegateCommand(RadGridViewLostFocus);
```

In the method 'RadGridViewLostFocus' set the bool property as false;

```
private void RadGridViewLostFocus()
{
    IsButtonEnabled = false;
 }
```

Comment: @mm8, I did try your code, `<ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding}"` But it is not working.

Comment: It means the button can not be disabled. It keeps the same status as before.

Comment: Does your property get set?

Comment: Yes, it has getter and setter.

Comment: So does the setter get hit?

Comment: I didn't test it since it was not working. Therefore I gave up the effort. But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: "Didn't test it since it was not working..."? How do you know that it wasn't working if you didn't test it?

Comment: I meant that I did't set a break point on getter or setter. But the button's status was not changed at all. I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interaction trigger from [System.Windows.Interactivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) and a `ChangedPropertyAction` from [Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicrosoftExpressionInteractions/):

```
<telerik:RadGridView xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                     xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding}" TargetName="IsButtonEnabled" Value="false" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
...
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) for information about how to handle events in a MVVM application.